Type arguments for a method reference can't be inferred from the usage
I'm getting this error in C# on .NET 8.0 (and .NET 6.0 if I'm being pedantic):

Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Foo.Execute<I, O>(Func<I, O>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

On this line:
Execute(Method);

In this snippet:
public class Foo
{
    public class Baz { }
    public class Bat { }

    public void Bar()
    {
        Execute((Baz baz) =>
        {
            return new Bat();
        });

        Execute(Method);
    }

    public Bat Method(Baz baz)
    {
        return new Bat();
    }

    public void Execute<I, O>(Func<I, O> func)
    {
    }
}

Is there any way I can go about adjusting my setup here so I don't have to explicitly include Baz into the line of code in question here?
I know I can do:
Execute((Baz baz) => Method(baz));

But that kinda rubs me the wrong way. I'm trying to avoid having to specify types in more than just the method's location, and as far as I'm concerned that Baz in the lambda is still explicitly typing it.
Thanks for any help :)

Usually, if type inference isn't working, the most straightforward fix is to do what the compiler suggests and just make the types explicit. What's your specific reason for wanting to avoid having Execute<Baz, Bat>(Method); ?

@Damien_The_Unbeliever the mission for code cleanliness!
in my production app, I have a bunch of method overloads for Execute with varying types to encompass a hearty API.
Specifying types here is the easy solution, but I'd really like for my API users to be able to define methods separately wherever they like, then they can call Execute(SomeMethodReference) and everything's nice and clean and they wouldn't have to change the typing in two different locations if they change it in the future for example. It's super pedantic but was curious nonetheless! :')

In this line:
Execute(Method);

The compiler cannot infer the generic types for Execute, because Method is not a Func<I, O> (although it can be converted to one).
To solve it, as suggested by the compiler ("Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."), you can explicitly specify the generic types for Execute in the following way:
//------vvvvvvvv----------
Execute<Baz, Bat>(Method);

A side note:
In order to actually do something in Execute with Func<I,O> func (i.e. call it), you need to also pass the relevant I parameter to call it with.

Your Execute() function takes a function variable. Method is not a variable. You need to create a variable like
private readonly Func<Baz, Bat> fnMethod = (baz) => Method(baz);

then you can invoke
Execute(fnMethod);

And yes, your anonymous function does pretty much the same. My code simply spells it out. The benefit is that if you have numerous invocations, you specify type in two places
If you really want to specify only once, I suppose you can do this:
private readonly Func<Baz, Bat> fnMethod = baz => new Bat();

and you don't need Method() at all. In real world you will likely have the body of the function instead of simply new Bat() - but I think you got the point

"Method is not a variable. You need to create a variable ..." - This is incorrect. You can call Execute with any callable that can be converted to Func<I, O>, including Method. The problem is the inference of types. See my answer.

@wohlstad - nomenclature aside, with functional variable approach, you need to specify types only once - in variable initialization. Compiler can infer the types. That's why I would prefer mine. Although, true, - both will work

I agree both can work. It is a matter of personal preference. I just meant that in the OP's code the problem is inference of types (not the issue of Method not being a variable), and my answer solves it.
